# Integrate User Registration with Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm currently trying to design and build an ASP.NET core application which will allow users to login via Azure AD. My goal is to have a web application that is hosted in Azure that allow (internal/external) users to login with our/their company's azure ad to access the application's functionality with a profile.

I'm looking to implement the workflow:

Step 1) User logs in with their Company email and authenticates with their company's Office 365 log-in. (I was able to get this working using the ASP.NET core sample project).

Step 2) If it's the users' first time, they are prompted with a registration page where they configure their profile. The profile information would be tracked in an internal sql server database. Their profile would be locked until an administrator completed the configuration/activation of their profile.

Step 3) If the user is already registered, their profile would be retrieved and loaded and the application would load the home page for the application so the user can access all the features they are allowed to.

I'm stuck on implementation Step 2. It's possible this isn't a great design and would welcome feedback to improve the workflow of an authenticated users accessing the web application.

For some history, I previously created an ASP.NET 4.5 MVC application (using the sample Visual Studio generates) where the users are internally tracked and registered, but I'm unable to figure out how to connect Step 1 to Step 2 when using ASP.NET core and Azure AD. I have no experience with Azure AD, and I'm a beginner with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite broad.

I suggest you take a look at [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x). It allows you to outsource the authentication to Azure AD (and many other login providers), and also have a local user database with profile information.

Using standard Entity Framework methods to extend data classes and add migrations to the database, you can add profile information to your local database.

For some reason there is no sample that integrates Azure AD and ASP.NET Core Identity, so you have to see what needs to be done by looking at 
the [other external providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/).

In short, you add the identity framework with these lines in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDbConnectionString")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and then add Azure AD authentication using Open ID Connect:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(
        o =>
        {
            o.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
            o.Authority = String.Format(
                        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"]);
            o.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        });
```